# access jquery variable in php code in the same page

Tags: php, jquery

How can i get the jquery varaible value and use it in the where clause of the php. Is there is even a way to do this in the same page?

**jquery:**

```
$(".some").click(function()
{   
    var value = $(this).attr('rel');
}
```

**php:**

```
$query = oci_parse($con,"SELECT * FROM cd WHERE cid = '".$_GET["value "]."'");
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: something like this?

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { value }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is **AJAX**. You can't add an elements' **rel** attribute value to an SQL query, that too on clicking of the element. What you can do is, send a request to a special page (or same page) to fetch the stuff from database.

Then, by using the response you can make changes on the body.

```
$(".some").click(function(){   
 var RelValue = $(this).attr('rel');
 $.get("url_to_php_file", {value: RelValue}, function(data){
  // Make changes on current page
 });
});
```

An example of making the content of the clicked element to "loaded" when the **AJAX** response is received :

```
$(".some").click(function(){   
 var RelValue = $(this).attr('rel');
 var t=$(this);
 $.get("url_to_php_file", {value: RelValue}, function(data){
  t.text("loaded");
 });
});
```

See more about AJAX : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

See more about **jQuery.get()** : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: i didn't understand this. how can i use this relvalue in php code?

Comment: @user3400389 jQuery will send a rquest to PHP file with the value of the `rel` attribute when the `.some` is clicked. Else is up to you. By analysing the AJAX response, you can make any changes on current page using jQUery

Comment: thanks. i will try and will give my reponse.

Answer (score 0):

```
        $(".some").click(function()
        {   
            var value = $(this).attr('rel');
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "yourphppage.php",
            data: { value: value }
            })
           .done(function( msg ) {
            //alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
}
```